# Three horse race

Tags: mathematics, probability

There are three horses in the race. You know the following information about them:

- Horse A will finish the race in 50 or 60 seconds with both events being equally likely.
- Horse B will always finish the race in 55 seconds.
- Horse C will finish the race in 53 or 57 seconds with both events being equally likely.

Which horse is most likely to win?

Comment: Nothing is stated about the probabilities of A and C finishing in the two timings. So what does "most likely" mean in this case?

Comment: Added this information.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A slightly different approach

> 50 seconds is the fastest time listed so Horse A has at least 1/2 a chance to win the race. Given that there are scenarios where Horse B or C could win, this means that neither of their chances can be as high as 1/2 so Horse A must be most likely to win.

Comment: I don't understand this argument: *"Given that there are scenarios where Horse B or C could win, this means that neither of their chances can be as high as 1/2"*. Why could neither of their chances be as high as 1/2?

Comment: @Stef Because the sum of the probabilities will be 1, the sum of the probabilities of B or C winning is <= 1/2 and since they are both non-zero, they must also be both less than 1/2

Comment: Where did you get *"and since they are both non-zero"* from?

Comment: @Stef They are both non-zero because there are scenarios where they both can win. If something is possible, then it has probability greater than zero.

Comment: But how do you know that it's possible? That's not stated in the problem. You're making an assumption there.

Comment: @Stef No, it's not an assumption, it's very clear from the information given - B wins if A is 60 and C is 57,  C wins if C is 53 and A is 60.

Comment: Yes, *if* A is 60 and C is 57, *then* B wins. But from the information given in the problem, you *cannot* conclude that the joint probability of A=60, C=57 is nonzero. Similarly, from the information given in the problem, you cannot conclude that the joint probability of C=53, A=60 is nonzero.

Comment: @Stef So you're getting into loopywalt's argument which is quite a philisophical one. My argument to that would be since it is not mentioned that A and C are correlated then it is possible that they are not.

Comment: A and C are not correlated and that has never been mentioned.

Comment: @hexomino I completely agree that *"since it is not mentioned that A and C are correlated then it is possible that they are not"*. Please note the difference between "we don't know anything about the correlation between A and C" and "We know that the correlation between A and C is exactly 0". Your answer makes the assumption that A and C are not independent and that their correlation is exactly 0. Loopywalt specifically does not make any assumption about A and C's correlation. In fact, they quite explicitly state that we have no information regarding that.

Comment: @Stef I'm not making the assumption that the correlation is exactly 0, that's wrong. I'm simply stating that it's possible that the correlation is not 1.

Comment: Oops, you're right, you're not making the assumption that the correlation is exactly zero. But what do you mean when you say "it's possible that the correlation is not 1"? Note that it is not correct to say "the probability that the correlation is not 1 is nonzero." Because there are no probabilities on this. The value of the correlation is not the result of a probabilistic experiment. The only probabilistic experiments in the problem are the horses finishing with a random time.

Comment: @Stef Are you familiar with the concept of a prior from Bayesian statistics?

Comment: @hexomino Because then you're answering a different problem. The problem statement describes a situation, and asks a question. Solving the problem means answering in all generality, so that the answer applies to any situation that fits the description. Placing a prior on the possible scenarios is really interesting and leads to an interesting answer, but it's an answer to a slightly different problem. Statisticians who choose their own priors are not solving a well-stated formal problem: they're modelling a problem themselves, then solving the problem under that model.

Comment: @Stef Note that I'm not choosing a prior here. I'm simply stating that the prior is not one where Scenario 1 has probability 1. To refute that would be specifying the prior.

Comment: @hexomino Still, you are saying that there is a distribution of probabilities on the scenarios, even if you don't know the exact probabilities of each scenario. So you're answering a different problem where the scenarios are random events. In the given problem, the only random events are the finish-times of the horses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132386/discussion-between-hexomino-and-stef).

Answer (score 24):

It is

> not possible to tell.

The following scenarios are compatible with the information given:

Scenario 1:

> A and C are 100% correlated, i.e. whenever A finishes in 50, C will finish in 53 and likewise with 60 and 57. Then A and B are tied with both expected to win half the races.

Scenario 2:

> A and C are 100% anti-correlated, i.e. whenever A finishes in 50, C will finish in 57 and likewise with 60 and 53. Then A and C are tied with both expected to win half the races.

Scenario 3:

> A and C are neither perfectly correlated nor anti-correlated. Then A wins half the races and B and C both win less than half.

Comment: That's an interesting way to look at it.

Comment: That's why in probability puzzles people always repeat "independently uniformly random".

Comment: But could you deduce from those three scenarios that A is most likely to win if you combine the results? A is always expected to win half the races in every scenario, whereas B and C are expected to win less often (Once half the races and once less than half)

Comment: I'm with @QBrute. The very purpose of assigning probability is not to reflect complete information but to *estimate based on incomplete information*. You should estimate the likelihood of each scenario and factor that in. Personally, I find scenario 3 to be far more likely both because it's more realistic and almost definitely what the question intended in the first place.

Comment: @TheRubberDuck You are confounding probability and statistics, a common mistake. Whatever your reasons to believe scenario 3 is more likely I'd be willing to bet that the same reasons render a horse that finishes a track in either 50 or 60 seconds (and never in, say 55 seconds or 51.62 seconds) utterly implausible. As neither of us has any experience of a world where racing times are distributed binary there is no point in arguing what joint probabilities might be more reasonable to assume.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Rather impressively, in a question with lots of loose ends you manage to get the one thing wrong that is actually set in stone. No matter which scenario A is expected to win *exactly* half the races. Whether A wins or not is completely independent of B and C and solely determined by A's time if it is 50 A wins, if it is 60 someone else wins.

Comment: @QBrute while in the absence of better knowledge it may be tempting to "mix" scenarios 1, 2 and 3 the way they are phrased they are actually mutually exclusive. So what you are getting at is probably a preference for scenario 3. See my answer to TheRubberDuck for why I don't agree.

Comment: Whoops, got some details wrong but the idea still stands . Allow me to revise - no matter the circumstance, A always wins half the races, while B or C can win *at most* half of the races, and possibly less. If all of these three scenarios are indeed possible with non-zero probability, regardless of how likely each one is, A is expected to win half of the races, while B and C are expected to win *less* than half. To claim that A is not more likely to win than B or C implicitly assumes that Scenario 3 is impossible, which there is no justification for.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie *"To claim that A is not more likely to win"* But I make no such claim. I'm saying we cannot tell. Please refer to my answer to TheRubberDuck for why I don't see any grounds for preferring any scenario over any other.

Comment: Exactly, there is no reason to prefer any scenario over the other - all are possible, and regardless of what (non-zero) probabilities you put on them, A is overall the most likely to win. The only way that A is *not* uniquely the most likely to win is if you are 100% sure that either Scenario 1 or Scenario 2 are the case, and as you point out, there is no grounds to assume that. If you admit the possibility of all of these scenarios, A is most likely to win.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie As I mentioned in another answer, the three scenarios are mutually exclusive, they cannot be mixed (because there is only one joint distribution). If I may be so bold as to second guess your intuition what you are doing is assuming scenario 3. I do not have to prove that 3 is impossible for 1 or 2 to be possible.

Comment: Call the probabilities of each scenario p1, p2, and p3 (all of which are non-zero), and the probabilities of B or C winning in Scenario 3 as pB and pC (both of which take values from 0 to 0.5, exclusive). The overall chance of A winning is 0.5p1 + 0.5p2 + 0.5p3 = 0.5 The chance of B winning is 0.5p1 + 0p2 + pBp3, which is always less than 0.5. The chance of C winning is 0p1 + 0.5p2 + pCp3, which is also less than 0.5. The only way A is not the most likely to win is if p3=0 and one of p1 or p2=0. If all scenarios are possible, A is most likely to win.

Comment: A always has a 50% chance of winning. B or C have at most a 50% chance of winning, and possibly less. If there is any chance at all that B or C have a less than 50% chance of winning, *they do not have a 50% chance of winning*, and therefore have a lower chance than A.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Nope, you cannot average over scenarios. Only one of them can be correct, we just do not know which.

Comment: @loopywalt NuclearHoagie is saying if you consider all the scenarios possibilities you don't know, that becomes part of the problem to solve. It's an interesting take, but incorrect, because if you don't know what the probabilities of each scenario are, which you assert, then that means the answer is A.

Comment: @InternetHobo no, sorry, you are missing the point. The scenarios *have no probabilities* because that would be a conceptual nonsense. For example, scenario 1 asserts that the joint probability p(A=50,B=55,C=57) equals zero. Now if you go ahead and assign a "probability" p1 to scenario 1 what would that mean? The probability p(A=50,B=55,C=57) equals 0 with probability p1? Does that strike you as a sound way of looking at things? It shouldn't  because it isn't.

Comment: @loopywalt In scenario 1 the horse most likely to win is A (tied); In scenario 2 the horse most likely to win is A (tied); In scenario 3 the horse most likely to win is A; One of these scenarios is correct, you don't know which one, if you assert they are all possible then A is most likely overall.

Comment: @loopywalt If I have three fair dice, one of which has A marked on half the faces and B on the other half, one has A on half the faces and C on the other faces and one has A on half the faces and an even split of B or C on the others, and I rolled one die under a cup, but I won't tell you which one I rolled, you're missing the point if you don't understand that A is the most likely face to be shown.

Comment: @InternetHobo It is true that we could imagine a problem where the three scenarios listed by loopywalt in the answer each have a probability. But that's not the problem asked by the OP. The problem asked by the OP is exactly the problem answered by loopywalt, and the conclusion for that problem is that P(A wins) is exactly 50%, but P(B wins) and P(C wins) are unknown because we don't have enough information. Just because this is a problem involving probabilities does not mean you can "add missing information" with a probability distribution on the possible values of that missing information.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky It's not just an interesting way to look at it. Currently it's the only correct answer. Every other answer, even the accepted answer, make extra assumptions.

Comment: @Stef what extra assumptions are being made in the accepted answer?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky In the accepted answer: *"Given that there are scenarios where Horse B or C could win, this means that neither of their chances can be as high as 1/2"* Here they make the assumption "there is a nonzero probability that B will win, and there is a nonzero probability that C will win". This cannot be deduced from your problem statement (as explained in loopywalt's answer), and is thus an extra assumption.

Comment: @Stef hmmm, but B or C will win when A runs for 60 seconds. So their chance of winning is non-zero. What am I missing?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky "B or C will win", yes. The probability that *one of them* wins is 50%. From that we can deduce P(B wins) + P(C wins) >= 50%.We also know they can't be tied. So we can deduce P(B wins) + P(C wins) = 50%. But you cannot deduce P(B wins) > 0 nor can you deduce P(C wins) > 0. Perhaps they're both nonzero, or perhaps one is 0 and the other is 50%. In the three scenarios listed by loopywalt, we have: Scenario 1: P(C) = 0, P(B)=50%. Scenario 2: P(B) = 0, P(C)=50%. Scenario 3: 0 < P(C) < 50% and 0 < P(B) < 50%. The assumption made in the accepted answer is that we are in scenario 3.

Comment: @Stef well we can break it down further. B will win when A runs 60 and C runs 57. C will win when A runs 60 and C runs 53. It seems that both of those scenarios will happen eventually, giving P(B wins) > 0 and P(C wins) > 0. The only way this breaks down is if A and C are correlated 100% - ie C gets the same time every time A gets 60. But the problem does not say that they are correlated.

Comment: *"B will win when A runs 60 and C runs 57"*. That is correct, but it begs the question: What is the joint probability of "A runs 60 and C runs 57"? There is no way to deduce from your problem statement that this probability is nonzero. You say *"It seems that both of those scenarios will happen eventually"* but that would be an extra assumption. How do you know that those scenario will happen? You don't.

Comment: Ok I see the issue and I agree with you. I could fix it but stating that they are not correlated. But that would be boring. I like this alternative interpretation and will keep the problem as is. In the "usual" layman interpretation the accepted answer is correct. While in the strict mathematical interpretation this answer would be correct.

Comment: @Stef But this answer makes another assumption, namely that we are *definitely not* in Scenario 3. The accepted answer does not assume that Scenario 3 is the case, it just *admits the possibility* that it is the case. There is non-zero probability that B or C will win, since we cannot assume with 100% confidence that we are in Scenarios 1 or 2. To say that A may not be the most likely to win is to be sure that one of either B or C never wins. If B and C both have a possibility of winning (and they do), then A is most likely to win.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie You can't do that. This answers never makes the assumption that we are definitely not in scenario 3, it just states "we don't know which scenario we're in". You're not allowed to place a distribution of probabilities on the scenarios either; we must be in one of the three scenarios, we just don't know which one. It might be scenario 3. Or scenario 1. Or scenario 2. Which scenario we're in is not specified in the problem statement.

Comment: The important thing is that in all 3 scenarios, **A** is *a* most likely to win horse.  So **A** is the correct answer.  The fact that the characteristic "most likely to win" may be shared with another does not remove it from **A**.

Comment: This answer is by far the most interesting, but that fact that it's incorrect means it's not the best answer. The fact that we don't know which scenario we're in is enough to know **A** *must* be the answer to "Which horse is most likely to win?" The fact that it might not be *more* likely to win than a different horse doesn't mean it's not *most* likely to win. The same way "What the square root of four?" gives enough information to say "2" confidently, even though it could also be "-2", even if I don't know what base the question is in.

Comment: @InternetHobo "The square root" is *defined* to be the **positive** square root for positive real numbers, precisely for that reason. You can talk about the **set of** 
 square root**s** of a number when you're actually solving something, and "the" square root is not useful for negative or complex numbers, precisely due to the branch cut.

Comment: And lol, another frequentist vs Bayesian flamewar. As stated, the question is frequentist and so "undefined" is correct. The answer is **exactly one** of "A or B", "A", or "A or C", and "averaging scenarios" is the same perennial confusion over what a p-value *means*.

Comment: @obscurans Interesting, haha. Can you explain more on how the question (and its intended answer) is frequentist, and that this (loopy) answer is bayesian?

Comment: Here is a thought. If you assume that each of the three scenarios is equally likely to occur then in expectation A will win more often :P

Comment: @justhalf I think obscurans' comment was saying exactly the opposite. The question is asked in a frequentist way, and loopywalt' answer is correctly answering the question. Any answer that says "we should put probabilities and the different possible scenarios" is actually answering a different problem (a Bayesian one). Bayesian and frequentist reasonings are both great and I see no reason to argue for one of for the other, but loopywalt's answer is the only one correctly answering this problem exactly.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me more by answering this question: what makes this question a frequentist one?

Comment: [Bayesian statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_statistics) is where you are allowed to express degrees of belief in scenarios, with a crucial point being you have to specify your *prior* beliefs before seeing the data. This question has nothing of the sort, and simply asks for "the" correct answer, leaving no room for mixing scenarios. There is One True scenario, and the problem leaves it underspecified.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming horse performance is uniformly distributed between the two possibilities for A and C *and they are independent*,

> $$\begin{array}{c|cc}C,A&50&60\\\hline53&A&C\\57&A&B\end{array}$$

Therefore

> A is most likely to win.

Comment: Assuming multiple races A  will win twice as often as the other horses.

Answer (score 6):

> Horse A
>
>  Horse A will win 1/2 the time, horses B and C will each win 1/4 the time.

Because

> 1/2 the time Horse A will run the race in 50 seconds, and neither horse B
>  or horse C are capable of running that fast.  Therefore Horse A will win
>  those races.
>
>  In the other 1/2 of the races horse A will run the race in 60 seconds and
>  place 3rd because no other horse will run the race that slowly.  But 1/2 of
>  those times horse C will run in 53 seconds and beat horse B, the other 1/2
>  of those times horse C will run in 57 seconds and lose to horse B.

Comment: This answer makes the extra assumption that the events listed in the problem are independent, which wasn't stated in the question; yet the word "independent" doesn't even appear in this answer. So, you're basing your calculations on an unspoken extra assumption.

Comment: When two times are given with 'equally likely' specified, doesn't that mean there are no dependencies?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Imagine the following situation: everyday the horses are fed the same menu. When horse A is fed broccoli, it runs in 50 seconds. When horse C is fed broccoli, it runs in 53 seconds. When horse A is fed lasagna, it runs in 60 seconds. When horse C is fed lasagna, it runs in 57 seconds. Now, I tell you that the probability that today's menu is broccoli is 50%, and the probability that today's menu is lasagna is 50%. Then you can safely conclude:

Comment: Then you can safely conclude: "Horse A will finish the race in 50 or 60 seconds with both events being equally likely." and "Horse C will finish the race in 53 or 57 seconds with both events being equally likely." Yet the events "A finishes in 50 seconds" and "C finishes in 53 seconds" are certainly not independent.

Comment: However, in the problem statement, we are not told whether the horses are fed the same menu, or a different menu, or independent menus, or something else. Any assumption we make in that regard is an extra assumption.

Comment: In your example then Horse A would win 1/2 the time (when all horses are fed broccoli) and Horse B would win the other 1/2 the time (when all horses are fed lasanga), right?   I would expect such dependencies to be spelled out in the question.  I think it's contrived to assume some dependency that has to itself be an equal probability for both statements to be true, however I can see the value in asking "why" Horses A and C have such different timings with equal probability.  In a real world scenario I would think track conditions would be a more likely factor.

Comment: But this is just a puzzle and in a real world scenario there would never be a horse that would run a race in two different times with equal probability in the first place, no matter how you tune the factors.

Comment: *"I think it's contrived to assume some dependency that has to itself be an equal probability for both statements to be true"* I agree; it's more than just contrived, it's wrong. We can't assume anything that isn't spelled out in the problem statement. We cannot assume that the events are not independent, and we cannot assume that the events are independent. We have to solve the problem with only the information given in the problem statement. And the answer is: P(A wins) = 50%, and P(B wins or C wins) = 50%, but P(C wins) and P(B wins) cannot be calculated because we lack information.

Comment: @Stef I disagree.  Given the information in the problem, `Horse C will finish the race in 53 or 57 seconds with both events being equally likely.`  It does not say that horse C will finish in 53 seconds if fed broccoli and 57 seconds if fed lasagna.  The statement does not declare any dependent factors that would result in the discrepancy, and with the given information it should be assumed to be completely random.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. Horse C's result is completely random, with 50% chance of finishing in 53 seconds and 50% chance of finishing in 57 seconds. And we have absolutely no information about how correlated this is with Horse A's finishing times. And since we have no information, we can't just assume. Perhaps Horse C wins 25% of the time, or perhaps Horse C wins 0% of the time, or perhaps 50% of the time, or perhaps some other number. There is no way to know.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat "and with the given information it should be assumed to be completely random." Agree! But note that "it should be assumed to be completely random" is not equal to "it should be assumed to be not dependent". They may still be dependent, or independent, we don't know.

Comment: @Stef, btw, I found more insightful observations and discussions on [my answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/114196/1649). Do you have a comment (if you want)? Especially since I think I've [nailed down the differences](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/113068/three-horse-race/114196?noredirect=1#comment319684_114196) in assumption in the two views, but I'm not sure how to resolve them (if even possible) in some way.

Answer (score 4):

I found the existing answers insightful, but I find that I'm still confusing between scenarios and probabilities. But I found another answer that is helpful to me, and it has not been posted here, so here we go.

Let's denote the joint probability of (A finish in 50 seconds AND C finish in 53 seconds) as $p$ (formally, $p(A=50 \wedge C=53) = p$). Also note that the marginal probability of A finishing in 50 seconds is 0.5, since it has equal probability to A finishing in 60 seconds. Then we have the following:

$
p(A=50 \wedge C=53) = p\\
p(A=50 \wedge C=57) = 0.5-p\\
p(A=60 \wedge C=53) = 0.5-p\\
p(A=60 \wedge C=57) = p
$

A wins when A finishes in 50 seconds, regardless of others, so $p(A\text{ wins}) = p + (0.5-p) = 0.5$.

B wins when A finishes in 60 seconds, and C in 57 seconds, so $p(B\text{ wins}) = p$

C wins when A finishes in 60 seconds, and C in 53 seconds, so $p(C\text{ wins}) = 0.5-p$

**Now, the question doesn't specify $p$.** So we can only rely on the information above with one unknown ($p$).

If $p=0.5$, then A and B have the same probability to win, if $p=0$, then A and C have the same probability to win, otherwise, A is the most likely to win.

Now, also "the most likely to win" is not defined in the question in the case there are two candidates with the same probability. If the question intends it to say that neither are most likely to win, then we don't have an answer, since we don't know $p$, and so we don't know whether there is a single candidate with highest probability to win.

However, if we consider two candidates having equal probability as both most likely to win, then A is most likely to win in all possible values of $p$. In this case we can say that **A is most likely to win in all scenarios, although we don't know whether B or C shares that title as well**.

For me this thought process is helpful since I couldn't see "scenarios" in loopy's answer as "something that we cannot assign probability to", but I can understand it when I put a variable $p$ to represent the scenario. (To be clear, I'm basically saying that this answer is the same as loopy's answer, but I came to understanding of the situation better through this formulation instead of loopy).

Comment: I like this reformulation of the answer to clarify things. In the context of this answer, my point from before is that $p$ will have some prior which is neither concentrated at 0 nor at 0.5 - note we do not need to know what the prior is just that it is not concentrated on a specific value, which seems fair since the intention is not specified. Then averaging over this prior gives A the highest probability of winning. Stef argued that you can't do this but I don't see why not.

Comment: I don't think we can do that. Consider the following statement: "This box contains a ball with probability $p$, otherwise it's empty." Can you say that it has non-zero probability of containing a ball, since if we put a prior over $p$, it's not concentrated on specific value 0?

Comment: @hexomino sorry forgot to ping

Comment: It may sound strange but in the absence of more information, I would say that *" it has non-zero probability of containing a ball"* because the contrary of that statement is *"it has zero probability of containing a ball"*

Comment: If $p=0$, then the statement "it has zero probability of containing a ball" is true. So we can't say that "it has zero probability of containing a ball" is false, because it could be true. @hexomino Another point, $p$ is the probability of the box containing a ball. So what you're saying is that we can derive $p\neq 0$ from just "The probability is $p$".

Comment: Not saying that $p \neq 0$ can be derived just that $p$ may not be zero and if we're not given any more information, we should assume that $p$ could take any value.

Comment: Hm, yea, I guess our differences is whether we view the process that generates $p$ as part of the probability space or not. For me if $p$ is unspecified, then the process that had generated $p$ doesn't matter, since I consider it to already be in the past. If instead the question specifies how to generate $p$, then I would include that in the probability space. So we differ in when we put our baseline for probability. I start it after $p$ is generated, and you start it before $p$ is generated. So in the multiverse of all values of $p$, you are outside any of them, while I'm inside one.

Comment: I think that's probably the right way to put it. It's very unusual to posit a problem with an inherent free parameter $p$ and then not ask for an answer in terms of $p$ but that is essentially what is happening here and then it comes down to how you work with that. Coming from a Bayesian background, my instinct is that one would use prior knowledge which seems reasonable to me because in problems about coin flips or dice rolls we never consider the correlation between the coins or dice unless it's specified.

Comment: But the bar isn't very high here because I'm not positing a prior, I'm just saying it's not one where $p$ is entirely centred on 0 or 0.5 because it seems that there is a possibility that horses may not be precisely correlated and that the author of the question may have some other value of $p$ in mind.

Comment: Yea, so you're taking into account the puzzle writer's thought into the prior. As in, "there is a possibility that the puzzle writer intends $p$ to be non-zero, so we can say that there is a non-zero probability for B and C to not be perfectly correlated". However, I would say that this isn't valid here, since we are already given a question, and the puzzle writer already has a fixed intention. So if we answer from the PoV of the question, there is no more assigning probability to the prior of $p$. But if we answer from the PoV of external observer ...

Comment: where there are multiple universe where in each universe there is this OP asking this question on Puzzling, but may have different intention, then or course we need to model the prior of $p$. Or I guess this is another view that "if it isn't incompatible with the observation, then there is a universe where it happens".

Comment: Interesting discussion overall. I don't know how to resolve our differences. But to respond to your remark "and then not ask for an answer in terms of $p$", I think usually if not mentioned, then you present the answer in terms of the unknowns. E.g., "I have some dogs and chickens, totaling to 10 animals. Do I own more than 30 animal leg?". Then your answer will be basically "well, that depends on how many dogs you have. I can make a formula that is based on the number of dogs $N$, but I can't do better than that." It's the same here, Stef's answer is saying "this is the formula based on $p$."

Comment: I completely agree with everything in this answer.

Comment: @justhalf With the dogs and chickens, I would say the analogous question is actually "is it more likely than not that I own more than 30 animal legs?"

Answer (score 1):

Test it out yourself, and see who is most likely to win.

```
import random


class Horse:

    def __init__(self, finish):
        self.finish = random.choice(finish)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count_a = 0
    count_b = 0
    count_c = 0

    for x in range(100000):
        horse_a = Horse([50, 60])
        horse_b = Horse([55])
        horse_c = Horse([53, 57])

        if horse_a.finish < horse_b.finish and horse_a.finish < horse_c.finish:
            count_a = count_a + 1

        if horse_b.finish < horse_a.finish and horse_b.finish < horse_c.finish:
            count_b = count_b + 1

        if horse_c.finish < horse_b.finish and horse_c.finish < horse_a.finish:
            count_c = count_c + 1

    print("HORSE A: " + str(count_a))
    print("HORSE B: " + str(count_b))
    print("HORSE C: " + str(count_c))
```

Comment: Nice work. What is the result of running this?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Horse A has a 50% chance of winning, while Horses B & C both have a 25% chance of winning.

Comment: This answer makes the extra assumption that the events listed in the problem are independent, which wasn't stated in the question; yet the word "independent" doesn't even appear in this answer. So, you're basing your simulations on an unspoken extra assumption.

Comment: @Stef Even worse than assuming "independent". This answer assumes that the events come from a pseudo random number generator ...

Comment: @WhatsUp It's called a simulation, you being able to work out the result in advance by performing a 'hack' to gain knowledge of the seed number makes no difference to the overall outcome of of the result, whether it came from a pseudo random number generator or an actual random number generator. (－‸ლ)